# From shapefile to Python NetworkX?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, coordinate-system, layouts, networkx

I am being baffled by how apparently poorly `NetworkX` reads a shapefile and builds a graph out of it.

Below is a graphical example of a fake network built with 27 polylines all snapped together, so there are no topological errors (`ArcGIS 10.3.1`, `License: Advanced`). The coordinate system is the British National Grid (OSGB36).

[image]

Now, when doing

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.read_shp('C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\TEST.shp') 
nx.draw(G, with_labels=False)
```

The result is a graph plotted according to the spring layout, so the *shape* of the file *is not preserved*. Also, the image shows **three** disconnected components, which are *absolutely fabricated*, since all segments in my shapefile were snapped. Also, the coordinates of the nodes are imported as labels.

[image]

I wonder what the usefulness of the `nx.read_shp()` function is, if you are not allowed to reproduce the shapefile *exactly*. This is especially true if you want to make sure that the connections are recreated accurately.

**This leads me to my question:** how to play with `NetworkX` so that the graph is not plotted in some meaningless way, but reproduces the network shown in the shapefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will pretty much depend on how your shapefile is. Is it segmented (the lines break, when they encounter intersections)?

I haven't used read_shp for networkx, so I'm not sure.

I guess that read_shp might do some work trying to figure everything out and that might be related to a precision issue. That should be configurable, but it's not.

Looking at the source (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/_modules/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.html#read_shp) you can see that networkx uses coordinate pairs as the keys. A slight difference in one of the keys will show what you are seeing, disconnected nodes/edges.

Try to investigate the nodes of the disconnected patches. I'm pretty sure one of the nodes have quite similar coordinates, but slightly different, thus making it another node.

Answer (score 14):

I might have found a nice `Python` solution referring to the very shapefile in the question, so I am posting it for future reference.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.read_shp('C:\Users\MyName\MyFolder\TEST.shp') 
pos = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes())}
X=nx.Graph() #Empty graph
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys()) #Add nodes preserving coordinates
l=[set(x) for x in G.edges()] #To speed things up in case of large objects
edg=[tuple(k for k,v in pos.items() if v in sl) for sl in l] #Map the G.edges start and endpoints onto pos
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(X,pos,node_size=100,node_color='r')
X.add_edges_from(edg)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(X,pos)
plt.xlim(450000, 470000) #This changes and is problem specific
plt.ylim(430000, 450000) #This changes and is problem specific
plt.xlabel('X [m]')
plt.ylabel('Y [m]')
plt.title('From shapefiles to NetworkX')
```

Result and comparison. The final shape of the network might be shrinked in some direction, this depending on the `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()` values used. With `plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))` or other squares things might improve.
[image]

Comment: glad it worked out.

Comment: Someone finds it funny to downvote random answers/questions without saying why. Appalling.

Comment: @FaCoffee  What about if we have to convert shapefile to a MultiDigraph

Comment: @osmjit This is an interesting question. As a starting point, I think you should look into [NetworkX's function that creates MultiDiGraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/classes.multidigraph.html#networkx.MultiDiGraph). Then, you need to figure out how to define edge directionality. If your goal is to model networks such as the power grid, my suggestion would be to use a simplified scheme, if possible. For example, this would involve turning multiple edges between two nodes into a unique edge. Hope this helps.

Comment: @FaCoffee Digraphs are workable in networkx but the needs to hadle the multiple egdes into same node.  Can you please make it more clear due to newwbie to networkx. it would be great help and I am stuck.

Comment: I think the best way to help is if you post a new question with your specific problem (include some images for clarity if you can). In my snippet, the first 2 lines of code will allow you to read the shapefile and extract the true X,Y coordinates. In the 3rd line, simply replace what you see with `G = nx.MultiDiGraph()`, and then proceed. MultiDiGraphs have paths, so you need to add them to your `G` using `G.add_path([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`. When importing a shapefile into NetworkX, the nodes are not identified by an ID such as `0` or `2` etc, but by a tuple with their coordinates `(X,Y)`.