# How to load a weighed shapefile in networkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have a added a length table in every line of my shapefile which contains lines that represent roads, and I want to create a weighted graph with this data using the length table as weights.

[image: My table]

I have used this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227909/from-shapefile-to-python-networkx) to load my shapefile and create the graph with NetworkX.

[image: My graph]

I am wondering how can I get the weights defined in the table "length", so I can show in my graph.

**Edited**
Result after using @gene 's solution to draw the graph.

```
pos = {v:v for v in weighted_G.nodes()}

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(weighted_G,'weight')


nx.draw_networkx_nodes(weighted_G,pos, node_size=10,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(weighted_G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
# plt.xlim(577000, 579500) #This changes and is problem specific
# plt.ylim(9718500, 9721000) #This changes and is problem specific
plt.xlabel('X [m]')
plt.ylabel('Y [m]')
plt.title('From shapefiles to NetworkX')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('graph.eps', format='eps', rasterized=False)
```

[image: Graph with weights]

Comment: You need from and to nodes, see add_edge in networkx help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many other solutions proposed in GIS SE to convert a shapefile into a graph with Networkx..

If you use the Networkx solution (`nx.read_shp()`), the original geometry and the field values are still present in the edge data (see [How to calculate edge length in Networkx](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213431/2581))

Open the shapefile with   [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) for example

```
import geopandas as gpd
graph = gpd.read_file('egdge.shp')
graph.head()
  FID    length                     geometry
0  0.0  139.7458  LINESTRING (750.9195417696708 -225.09097935036...
1  1.0  173.8602  LINESTRING (169.9697833632519 -134.27610827609...
2  2.0  183.0633  LINESTRING (10.24390243902439 -273.31707317073...
3  3.0   33.3517  LINESTRING (750.9195417696708 -225.09097935036...
4  4.0   74.5553  LINESTRING (232.6829268292683 -113.31707317073...
# first element
print graph.iloc[0]['length']
139.7458
```

Now, the same shapefile with Networxk

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_shp('edges.shp')
# first edges
first = G.edges()[0]
print first
((750.9195417696708, -225.0909793503697), (782.9268292682925, -361.1219512195121)
```

but with `data=True`

```
first = G.edges(data=True)[0]
print first
((750.9195417696708, -225.0909793503697), (782.9268292682925, -361.1219512195121), {'ShpName': 'edges', 'Json': '{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 750.919541769670786, -225.090979350369707 ], [ 782.926829268292522, -361.121951219512084 ] ] }', 'FID': 0.0, 'Wkb': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02@\x87w[8\xb7 V\xc0l"\xe9M\x86\xce`@\x88wj%v\xa2V\xc0v\x91\xf3\x83\x1f80', 'length': 139.7458, 'Wkt': 'LINESTRING (750.919541769670786 -225.090979350369707,782.926829268292522 -361.121951219512084)'})
print first[0] # first node
(750.9195417696708, -225.0909793503697)
print first[1] # second node
(782.9268292682925, -361.1219512195121)
print first[2] # properties
{'ShpName': 'edges', 'Json': '{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 750.919541769670786, -225.090979350369707 ], [ 782.926829268292522, -361.121951219512084 ] ] }', 'FID': 0.0, 'Wkb': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02@\x87w[8\xb7 V\xc0l"\xe9M\x86\xce`@\x88wj%v\xa2V\xc0v\x91\xf3\x83\x1f80', 'length': 139.7458, 'Wkt': 'LINESTRING (750.919541769670786 -225.090979350369707,782.926829268292522 -361.121951219512084)'}
print first[2]['length']
139.7458
```

Therefore

```
weighted_G = nx.Graph()
for data in G.edges(data=True):
   weighted_G.add_edge(data[0],data[1],weight=data[2]['length'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew about GeoPandas, seems like a easier solution.

Comment: It worked, and a could even draw the graph.

Answer (score 2):

This didn;t actually work for me (maybe because of updates), but below is the code that worked for me. Updated from the answers above.

I post this as a followup from [How to load a weighed shapefile in networkX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256955/how-to-load-a-weighed-shapefile-in-networkx)

So I have created a network with QGIS and OSM (openstreetmaps), and exported it into two files: nodes and edges using of shapefiles.

However, I have a lot of trouble converting this into an actual networkx graph, which I will use for my simulation model.
After reviewing the post(s) like this [How to load a weighed shapefile in networkX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256955/how-to-load-a-weighed-shapefile-in-networkx)

I wanted to create a network using the geolocations of the nodes, and connect them with edges with source-target pair and add attributes such as distance, cost, width.

I still have a lot of trouble actually adding weight and labels to the edges. If I follow that post, every step of the way should give the same results.

To figure out if there was something different with my shapefile than theirs, I used the following code:

```
  import geopandas as gpd
graph = gpd.read_file('/Users/01/Downloads/edge_data_length.shp')
print(graph.head())
```

Which gave the following results:

```
edge_id  start_node  end_node  next_left_  abs_next_l  next_right  \
0       45          63        64          50          50          45   
1       54          78        56         -54          54         -39   
2       39          55        78         -55          55          39   
3        6          11        12        -101         101          43   
4      110         121        60         -41          41         110   

   abs_next_r  left_face  right_face        cost  \
0          45          0           0  122.826431   
1          39          0           0  250.869815   
2          39          0           0   43.350826   
3          43          4           5  516.143133   
4         110          0           0  584.250999   

                                            geometry  
0  LINESTRING (4.8703865 52.364651, 4.8716933 52....  
1  LINESTRING (4.9264105 52.3695602, 4.9289823 52...  
2  LINESTRING (4.9259642 52.3692824, 4.9264105 52...  
3  LINESTRING (4.877608 52.3752153, 4.8778622 52....  
4  LINESTRING (4.8701251 52.3757447, 4.8706393 52...
```

Which looked good enough, but then I tried their code step for step but with no results.
Their code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_shp('edges.shp')
# first edges
first = G.edges()[0]
print first
((750.9195417696708, -225.0909793503697), (782.9268292682925, -361.1219512195121)
```

My code

```
  import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.read_shp('/Users/01/Downloads/edge_data_length.shp')
# first edges
first = G.edges(data = True)[1]
```

gives:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-be0a4d56d7fb> in <module>()
      3 G = nx.read_shp('/Users/01/Downloads/edge_data_length.shp')
      4 # first edges
----> 5 first = G.edges(data = True)[1]

TypeError: 'OutEdgeDataView' object does not support indexing
```

So I tried putting it in a list:

```
first = list(G.edges(data=True))
print(first[1])
```

And it gave the following result:

```
((4.8719547, 52.3651758), (4.8716814, 52.365598), {'edge_id': 50, 'start_node': 64, 'end_node': 70, 'next_left_': -50, 'abs_next_l': 50, 'next_right': -135, 'abs_next_r': 135, 'left_face': 0, 'right_face': 0, 'cost': 50.5301293256479, 'ShpName': 'edge_data_lengte', 'Wkb': b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02@\x13|\xe1\xb1`_\xbc@J.\xbe\x14\xa3%4@\x13|\x9a\x0c\x86 @@J.\xcb\xeaN\xbd\xd3', 'Wkt': 'LINESTRING (4.8719547 52.3651758,4.8716814 52.365598)', 'Json': '{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 4.8719547, 52.3651758 ], [ 4.8716814, 52.365598 ] ] }'})
```

Then I tried adding it to the graph, like the post was doing as well:

```
weighted_G = nx.Graph()
for data in first:
    weighted_G.add_edge(data[0],data[1],weight=data[2]['cost'])

pos = {v:v for v in weighted_G.nodes()}
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(weighted_G,'cost')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(weighted_G,pos, node_size=2,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(weighted_G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)
# plt.xlim(577000, 579500) #This changes and is problem specific
# plt.ylim(9718500, 9721000) #This changes and is problem specific
plt.xlabel('X [m]')
plt.ylabel('Y [m]')
plt.title('From shapefiles to NetworkX')
plt.show()
#plt.savefig('graph.eps', format='eps', rasterized=False)
```

It gave no errors this time, but it still got a graph without the weight "cost" for each edge. So now I changed this

```
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(weighted_G,'cost')
```

to:
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(weighted_G,'weight')