# How to create a weighted square lattice as well as a weighted network graph

Tags: python, python-2.7, shapely, networkx

I am planning to create a weighted square lattice for different sizes, and then label each edge with its associated weight. It's similar to this thread "[How to load a weighed shapefile in networkX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256955/how-to-load-a-weighed-shapefile-in-networkx)" that looks like intersection of different lines with different weights.

How can plot such a network and their weights? The weight can be for example just a random generator at this moment.

I have the following piece code from above page which does not work:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 10
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
weighted_G = str (np.random.rand()) 
pos = {v:v for v in weighted_G.nodes()}
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(weighted_G,'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(weighted_G,pos, node_size=10,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(weighted_G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)

# plt.xlim(577000, 579500) #This changes and is problem specific
# plt.ylim(9718500, 9721000) #This changes and is problem specific

plt.xlabel('X [m]')
plt.ylabel('Y [m]')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

## Set up a graph with random edges and weights

G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(6, 2, seed= 3214562)

for u,v in list (G.edges):

```
G[u][v]['weight'] = int(random.random() * 10)
```

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos)

plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

import networkx as nx

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import math

import random

N = 20
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)

pos = dict((n, n) for n in G.nodes())

print "pos",pos

label = dict(((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N) for i, j in G.nodes())

for u,v in list (G.edges):

```
G[u][v]['weight'] = int(random.random() * 10)
```

labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=labels)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, label=label)

print "labels", label

## print "weights", labels

plt.axis('off')

plt.figure()

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels =True)

plt.show()